# Recycler smooth scrolling occurs in every response from web

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, android-scrollview

Recycler scroll to bottom is applied using smoothScrollToPosition() in a chat application. Its looks jumping from top to bottom whenever response occurs from server.

```
RecycleViewObject.smoothScrollToPosition(array.size());
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried this recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1) ?

Comment: thanks, resolved scrolling from top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(ArrayList.size()-1);
```